# How can I start looking for extreme points in convex polytopes?

Tags: convex-analysis, linear-programming, polyhedra, polytopes, discrete-geometry

Consider $S  \subset \mathbb{R^2}$ a set such that $\forall (x_1,x_2) \in S$ :

$ 2x_1+3x_2 \leq 6 $

$-2x_1+ x_2 \leq 2$

$x_1 \geq 0 , x_2  \geq 0$

How can I find extreme points of $S$? What is a good strategy to start tackling this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $x_1,x_2\geqslant0$ we can write the inequalities as equalities with the use of slack variables:
\begin{align}
2x_1+3x_2+s_1&=6\\
-2x_1+x_2+s_2&=2\\
x_1,x_2,s_1,s_2&\geqslant 0.
\end{align}
Extreme points are equivalent to basic feasible solutions. Because $S\subset\mathbb R^2$, a basic solution has two basic variables; hence there are six candidates: $$(x_1,x_2), (x_1,s_1), (x_1,s_2), (x_2,s_1), (x_2,s_2), (s_1,s_2).$$
Solve the system of equations by setting each nonbasic variable equal to zero; if the resulting solution is positive, then it is feasible, and hence a basic feasible solution. I'll leave the computations to you, but the extreme points we find in this process are $(0,0), (3,0), (0,2)$ (in terms of $(x_1,x_2)$).

Answer (score 1):

Ummmm.... why don't you just plot it?

[image]

and analogously in higher dimensions:

[image]

Comment: This works fine for $\mathbb R^2$ but what about higher-dimensional problems? :)

Comment: What tool did you use for the second plot?

Comment: *Mathematica*'s `RegionPlot3D` functionality.